# JavaScript string 08-24-2021 cast to a date failed in firefox and safari but works in chrome

Tags: javascript, reactjs, google-chrome, firefox

I have these two code lines

```
console.log("type",typeof cartData.configuration.pickDate)
console.log("Date",new Date(cartData.configuration.pickDate))
```

**In chrome browser**

[image]

**In Firefox and safari**
[image]

This seems a browser-specific issue.
Even though I tried with moment js like this

```
moment(cartData.configuration.pickDate)
```

still, it gives me an invalid date.

How do I fix this?

**Updated!**

```
console.log(cartData.configuration.pickDate)
```

gives the string 08-24-2021

Comment: What is the output of `console.log(cartData.configuration.pickDate)`?

Comment: Try ```moment(cartData.configuration.pickDate).format("DD-MM-YYYY") ``` .

Comment: When you use moment you should specify the format of the value you're giving `moment('08-24-2021', 'MM-DD-YYYY').toDate()`

Comment: Have you considered that your different browsers might have different user locales set? Your chrome browser is set to a locale that uses the format MM-DD-YYYY and your Firefox and Safari are set to a locale that uses DD-MM-YYYY